# Android RecyclerView RecyclerViewPool

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to understand how RecyclerView works.

We know that when RecyclerView needs an ItemView, that RecyclerView's adapter provides the ItemView. To do so, the adapter first looks for that type of view inside some caches and at last inside the RecyclerViewPool (Check [this blog](https://android.jlelse.eu/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-404ba3453714) for the full list of checking). If the adapter doesn’t get the specified type of view inside the cache's or RecyclerViewPool, then it creates one inside the onCreateViewHolder method.

Now my question is, is there any way to check constantly, while scrolling the RecylerView list, what views are inside the RecyclerViewPool?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Why do you want to?  The entire point of recycler view is to abstract away those levels of details.

Comment: For curiosity and for understanding what is actually happening underneath.

Comment: If you're that curious, stick a breakpoint in there and watch what happens under the debugger.

Comment: Well that would be an overhead, wouldn't it? But it would be great to know if someone already tried it and if there have any method I can call to know what I want to know. That's why I am asking the question.

Comment: There isn't, because the point of it was to hide these details.  But if you're just curious- its open source.  You can always fork it, add a function, and use that version of the view in a test program.